# How to go through dynamic Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a web app that accesses a Firebase Real-Time Database. The database will be of a dynamic size as new data is entered.

example:

[image: database screenshot]

Each element holds an irrelevant object.

I've hard-coded the size and am for-looping through it (js):

```
for (let i = 0; i < DB_SIZE; i++) {
        let ref = firebase.database().ref(i.toString());
        let snapshot = await ref.once('value');
        let data = snapshot.val();
    }
```

The `data` achieved is the object associated with the element.

This works when I know the exact, unchanging size of the database, but when a new object is added as a new element in the database, my loop wouldn't access it, since the database size is now larger.

How can I access the data in this dynamic database using Firebase's syntax? It's possible that `try...catch` will be involved, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase `DataSnapshot` has a built-in `forEach` method precisely for this purpose. So you can load the entire parent node, and then loop over it client-side with:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref().once('value');
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    let data = child.val();
});
```

By the way, Firebase recommends against using sequential, numeric indexes as the keys. For an explanation why, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).